# Three.js load obj models from cache

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

i have a scene containing some obj models, i noticed that each time the page is reloaded the loader loads the objects again from url not from cache. is there is a method to check if the resource occurs in the cache loads it directly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I know, ThreeJS doesn't provide that feature embedded for large files. However, you can work with 3rd parties plugins to achive that.

There is a plugin called MicroCahce.js that enables to store objects in the GPU Cache. This plugin can be localized here:

https://github.com/jeromeetienne/MicroCache.js

And you can find the full tutorial step by step explained how to achieve this here:

http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/09/16/performance-caching-material/

Hope it helps!